# Issue on resizing the Console Window in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I keep getting issues with this code.

```
def changeWindowSize():
   cmd = "mode con: cols=107 lines=50"
   resize = os.system(cmd)
   subprocess.Popen(resize)
```

It does work, but then also generates a Traceback.

Here is the Traceback:
https://i.gyazo.com/e1fa638c083d2f05d391abf64a1e3778.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `os.system` is enough:

```
def changeWindowSize():
    cmd = "mode con: cols=107 lines=50"
    os.system(cmd)
```

If you want to use `subprocess.Popen`, call with `shell=True`:

```
def changeWindowSize():
    cmd = "mode con: cols=107 lines=50"
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    #  OR  subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

---

The script failed because it passed an integer object (return value of `os.system`) to `subprocess.Popen` which accepts a list or a string as the first parameter.

Comment: `shell=True` isn't necessary. It's an external PE executable, but for historical reasons the extension is .com instead of .exe, e.g. `subprocess.call('mode.com con cols=107 lines=50')`.

Comment: For reference, this is also the case with chcp.com, format.com, more.com, and tree.com. In 64-bit Windows these are all 64-bit PE executables located in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. They just happen to have the legacy .com extension that used to be used with the old MS-DOS 16-bit .COM filetype. Other than the name and command-line interface (for the most part) they have nothing in common with the original MS-DOS utilities in terms of their implementation. They're Win32 console applications.